# Primeng menubar items hide quick on Firefox & Edge

Tags: angular, firefox, microsoft-edge, primeng, menubar

I'm using Angular 4, primeNg 4.3.0, chrome Version 78.0.3904.108 (Build ufficiale) (a 64 bit) & Microsoft Edge 44.18362.329.0

I'm using a menubar to place a navigation bar to show some pages. I've changed the css of the menu bar since the colors didn't match with my app. The menubar works on Chrome, I can move the mouse to each item & subitem without any issue, but on Firefox & Edge the sub items hide very quickly. It seems the function onItemMouseLeave from the menubar gets activated between the bottom part of an item and the top part of the next item causing it to close the subitems of the menubar. here's the code:

template:

```
<section>
  <div id="menu-box2">
    <div class="container menucus">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <p-menubar #menu [model]="items" styleClass="menucus"></p-menubar>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

TS:

```
this.items = [
          {
            label: 'Action Types',
            items: [
              {
                label: 'Action 1',
                routerLink: ['/action/type1'],
                routerLinkActiveOptions: {
                  exact: true
                },
                styleClass: 'menucus'
              },
              {
                label: 'action 2',
                routerLink: ['/action/type1'],
                routerLinkActiveOptions: {
                  exact: true
                },
                styleClass: 'menucus'
              }
            ],
          },
          {
            label: 'Options',
            routerLink: ['/options'],
            routerLinkActiveOptions: {
              exact: true
            },
            styleClass: 'menucus',
          },
          {
            label: 'About',
            routerLink: ['/about'],
            routerLinkActiveOptions: {
              exact: true
            },
            styleClass: 'menucus',
          },
        {
            label: 'Action Types7',
            items: [
              {
                label: 'Action 9',
                routerLink: ['/action/type9'],
                routerLinkActiveOptions: {
                  exact: true
                },
                styleClass: 'menucus'
              },
              {
                label: 'action 10',
                routerLink: ['/action/type10'],
                routerLinkActiveOptions: {
                  exact: true
                },
                styleClass: 'menucus'
              },
              {
                label: 'action X',
                routerLink: ['/action/typeX'],
                routerLinkActiveOptions: {
                  exact: true
                },
                styleClass: 'menucus'
              }
            ],
            styleClass: 'menucus'
          },
    ];
```

CSS:

```
::ng-deep .ui-menu,.ui-menu .ui-menu-child{
    border: 0px;
    background:#5393bc 0 0 repeat-x !important;
}
::ng-deep .ui-menu .ui-menuitem .ui-menuitem-link:hover{
    background-color: #5393bc;
    border: none;
}
::ng-deep .ui-menu .ui-menuitem .ui-state-active{
    background-color: #5393bc;
}
::ng-deep .ui-menu .ui-menuitem.ui-menuitem-active>.ui-menuitem-link,
.ui-menu .ui-menuitem .ui-menuitem-link:hover{
    background-color:#186ba0;
    border: none;

}
::ng-deep .menucus{
    background: #5393bc !important;
}
::ng-deep .ui-menu .ui-menuitem-parent, .ui-menu .ui-menuitem{
    margin: auto;
}  
::ng-deep .ui-menuitem .ui-widget .ui-corner-all { 
    border-radius:0;
}

::ng-deep .ui-menu .ui-menu-parent .ui-menu-child{
    padding: 0;
}
```

I'm forcing the style to be on each item/subitem cause if I don't do it the default colors will be the ones of the PrimeNG menubar style.

as i said, on Chrome works like a charm, but on firefox & edge it doesn't work.

I can't update to a newer version of these because the place where I am doesn't allow me to do it, so if something is deprecated I can't help it. I need to find a way to do this. Thanks for your help.

---- Important ----
if I don't change de CSS, the only subitem that gets the same color of the menu is the first subitem of the first menu. If i use the nth:child(number), it adds a new rectangle of the size of the item at the bottom of the menu which has fewer items, so the nth:child solution doesn't work for me :(.

****UPDATE****
There is another CSS that modifies the menu-box2 and maybe that's what it is giving the problem. I removed the menu-box2 and the bar obviously doesn't show the colors but the problem on Edge has disappeared. Which means that I need to modify that CSS. But can't seem to find what's the part that is giving me this problem. I'll put the code here and then will try to do a plunkr (or whatever it's called xD.

Styles.SCSS which is in the root folder of the whole app.

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
@import "~primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css";
@import "~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
@import "~js4u-styles/scss/variables";
@import "theme/CompanyTheme";

$menu1-height: 60px;
$menu2-height: 50px;
$color-red-tag: #d32f2f;
$color-green-tag: #388e3c;
$color-auth-tag: #5393bc;

#menu-box {
  background-color: $u-blue;
  min-height: $menu1-height;
  a {
    line-height: $menu1-height;
  }
}

#menu-box2 {
  background-color: $u-blue-l;
  min-height: $menu2-height;
  a {
    line-height: $menu2-height;
  }
}

.header_logo {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.page-content {
  h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.ui-dropdown {
  min-width: 10px;
}

#menu-box,
#menu-box2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    li {
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100%;
      // font-size: 1.2em;
      // line-height: 40px;
      // height: 40px;
      // border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
      a {
        transition: background-color 0.2s;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        height: 100%;
        min-width: 120px;
        color: white;
        padding: 0 20px;
      }
      a.noLink {
        padding: 0;
        text-align: left;
      }

      a:hover,
      a:focus,
      a:active {
        // color: #999;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: color 0.1s, background-color 0.1s;
      }
      a {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        transition: color 0.1s, background-color 0.1s, padding 0.2s ease-in;
        color: #fff;
      }
      a::before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 5px;
        left: 0;
        height: 3px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        transform-origin: right top;
        transform: scale(0, 1);
        transition: color 0.1s, transform 0.2s ease-out;
      }

      a:hover::before,
      a:focus::before {
        transform-origin: left top;
        transform: scale(1, 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I tried to create a sample using your posted code, but not reproduce it. You could also try to use F12 developer tools to compare the CSS style in Chrome and Edge browser, whether there is some CSS style not working in Edge browser, Besides, please check whether you have attach some JQuery method on these elements?

Comment: I'll create it (first time creating that so it will take some time xD) But it seems that the problems is another styles.scss that calls the #menu-box2 (facepalm). Cause I remove it and the problems dissapears. I'll first update the info in the question to see what is causing this problem.

Comment: at the end it was an Style height/width at the style theme